# Angular always searches for assets folder in the parent folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a project with Angular 5 that I'm deploying on my server in /var/www/html/myproject . So I can get to it to 192.168.1.1/myproject.
Everything seems to work except for the 'assets' folder.

Instead of looking into 192.168.1.1/myproject/assets the server is still looking in 192.168.1.1/assets . I also tried to use 'deploy-url' in the ng build command but it remains the same.

Why is it still looking for the assets folder in the root?

This is my current command
"ng build --prod --bh /myproject/ --sourcemap --deploy-url /myproject/"

Comment: Maybe your base URL is set to `/` in your index.html. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp But I think your server can handle that (in your `.htaccess` for example, if you use that).

Comment: set the baseurl to `/myproject` rather `/`

Comment: sorry forgot to notice that I already set the baseurl.
This is the full command I used last time "ng build --prod --bh /myproject/ --sourcemap --deploy-url /myproject/" @RolandRácz I'll have a look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was that my image src was specified like `<img src='../../../assets/my_image.jpg'>` . It seems I had to change this src to `<img [src]="'assets/my_image.jpg'">` instead to make it work with the assets folder on the server.